# How do I theme my slidingDrawer so it have a nice dark bar?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a sliding drawer and I am trying to create the dark bar used in most application.  But I have no idea how Android Themeing works:

```
<SlidingDrawer 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:handle="@+id/SliderHeader" 
android:content="@+id/SliderContent"
style="@style/DarkThemeSelector">
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@id/SliderHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />
    </RelativeLayout >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/SliderContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Here is what I have:

```
<style name="DarkThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Dark">
</style>
```

This doesn't work as there is no such thing as android:Theme.Dark

Answer (score 0):

Here use this theme generator:-

[Android Holo Colors Theme Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Change whatever color you like & add generated components to respective folder...